# The meaning of 一丁前にてれちゃっても

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> 「あはははは、こんなもの慣れよ慣れ。ほら、じっとしてな、払ってあげるから」
>
> 「い、いーですって、先生、自分でしますから」
>
> 「**いっちょまえに照れちゃってもー**。いーからいーから、自分じゃわかんないでしょ。ほら、頭の上とか」

I don't quite understand how 一丁前に  modifies 照れちゃっても in this context. I understand that 一丁前に has the ideas of becoming an adult associated with it, but how does that come into play in this context? (She threw a snowball at him, and he hates the cold.)

Comment: As like other long vowel marks in your passage, this one after も is a part of word, too. So it's もう instead of も.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's teasing him. 一丁前に照れちゃって is something like "So you are no longer a kid, you know how to be shy!" (like an adolescent boy, in a situation like this where a woman touches a man)

もー at the end is もう, which is not a conjunction but an interjection like "gee", "whew". From a [dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/218382/meaning/m0u/):

> ５ 自分の判断・感情などを強める気持ちを表す語。**感動詞的にも用いる。**まさに。なんとも。「これは―疑う余地のない事実だ」**「嫌になっちゃうなあ、―」**

As you can see in the example above, もー like this is usually (but not always) preceded by a comma.

Comment: これ、英語でどう言うのが自然なんでしょう。"Wow, you've already grown up to be shy in a situation like this!" とか？